# First time login core php logic in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

**I dont' want to do it by using other modules**, ex rules, first_login etc

In theme **page.tpl.php** i want a logic that will check if user is logged in first time and show him some message,

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in a module, not in page.tpl.php.
Why do you only want to do it in page.tpl.php?
Module code may look like this:

```
function MODULENAME_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  // If this is user's first time log-in.
  if ($account->access == 0) {
    drupal_set_message('first time login');
  }
}
```

Comment: @peter

function modulename_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  // If this is user's first time log-in.
  if ($account->access == 0) {

    drupal_set_message('first time login');
  }
} 

Tried this one but doesnt work

Comment: why doesn't it work? is $account->access == 0 TRUE ?